# How to smartly list the columns of a matrix into data frames while preserving the column names?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

Say we have a matrix `M`.

```
#    n1 n2 n3 n4
# m1  1  4  7 10
# m2  2  5  8 11
# m3  3  6  9 12
```

In order to list the columns as `"data.frames"` we can do:

```
apply(M, 2, data.frame)
```

However, the listed data frames have weird and identical column names, e.g.:

```
# $n1
#    newX...i.
# m1         1
# m2         2
# m3         3
```

Same thing with `lapply`:

```
lapply(data.frame(M), data.frame)
# $n1
#   X..i..
# 1      1
# 2      2
# 3      3
```

The only way I have found to get my **expected output** so far is doing:

```
lapply(1:ncol(M), function(x) setNames(data.frame(M[,x]), colnames(M)[x]))
# [[1]]
#    n1  ## <-- expected col names!
# m1  1
# m2  2
# m3  3
```

This turns out to be unexpectedly cumbersome. Have I maybe missed a simpler **base** function?

#### Data

```
M <- structure(1:12, .Dim = 3:4, .Dimnames = list(c("m1", "m2", "m3"
), c("n1", "n2", "n3", "n4")))
```

Comment: Is `Map(stack, asplit(M, 2))` what you expect?

Comment: @tmfmnk Interesting, but actually not, please see edit for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be (a synthesis of my original post and the suggestion from @H 1):

```
split.default(data.frame(M), colnames(M))
```

It has the structure:

```
List of 4
 $ n1:'data.frame': 3 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ n1: int [1:3] 1 2 3
 $ n2:'data.frame': 3 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ n2: int [1:3] 4 5 6
 $ n3:'data.frame': 3 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ n3: int [1:3] 7 8 9
 $ n4:'data.frame': 3 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ n4: int [1:3] 10 11 12
```

Comment: Great solution! There's still a little overhead, though: `nchar("split.default(data.frame(M), names(data.frame(M)))") - nchar("apply(M, 2, data.frame)") ## 27`

Comment: @jay.sf a nice metrics :D With the updated post it is "just" 18 :)